# Install Newer version of app in android with Intent

Tags: android

I have an android app that at the start-up, checks to see if newer version of app is available or not. If newer version is available, the app downloads the .apk file and stores it in the SD Card. Now I want to ask launcher to install this new version. What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
    Intent installIntent= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
    installIntent.setData(Uri.parse("file:///path/to/your.apk"))
    installIntent.setType("application/vnd.android.package-archive");
    installIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(installIntent);
```

It will prompt the Installer-View. A direct silent installation is not possible if your app is not signed with the same key as the PackageManager.

Comment: I got an Exception: `android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW typ=application/vnd.android.package-archive }`

Comment: I added `installIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);` and everything goes fine!

Comment: I have an issue with webintent in cordova in android 9 (pie). Do you have any solution for this? because in android 6 i can update my app easily but in android 9 it says failed to open url via android intent

Comment: It's just a wild guess with this little info, but between 6 and 9 there were some changes concerning file access - maybe your apk is stored in a restricted folder.